# Alternative way of commenting in Bitbucket

Tags: eclipse, ide, bitbucket-server

I've a question about commenting in Bitbucket. If I click on "diff" I have the possibility to compare two branches and i can comment each line of code with a separate comment.
Is there any possibility to have to same functionality with a command line tool or API or is this only possible with the webinterface?
I ask because I'm looking for a way to have this functionality in an IDE like eclipse f.e. via plugin.

Comment: Are you talking about bitbucket.org or bitbucket server?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say: The Bitbucket server.

Comment: do you mean a diff on the pull request page?

Comment: That's right, it's the diff page of a Pull Request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming it is a pull request diff. Looking at the [documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/static/rest/bitbucket-server/5.1.0/bitbucket-rest.html#idm45588160314352) for the `File line comment` instructions block, shows that you can use the following request body

```
 {
     "text": "A pithy comment on a particular line within a file.",
     "anchor": {
         "diffType": "COMMIT",
         "line": 1,
         "lineType": "CONTEXT",
         "fileType": "FROM",
         "fromHash": "6df3858eeb9a53a911cd17e66a9174d44ffb02cd",
         "path": "path/to/file",
         "srcPath": "path/to/file",
         "toHash": "04c7c5c931b9418ca7b66f51fe934d0bd9b2ba4b"
     }
 }
```